# PHP MySQL query returning zero results when table has data

Tags: php, html, mysql

My PHP query is returning zero results when the table has 10 rows. What is actually displayed is a portion of the PHP table formatting code.

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

```
0) { // output data of each row while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { echo "in: " . $row["in"]. " - Name: " . $row["Name"]. " - Email: " . $row["Email"]. "
"; } } else { echo "0 re
sults"; } mysql_close($conn);?
```

HTML/PHP CODE:

```php
<div class="about-text">

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "in: " . $row["in"]. " - Name: " . $row["Name"]. " - Email: " . $row["Email"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysql_close($conn);
?>

</div>
```

Comment: you must stop using mysql_  -- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: check out http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

replace

```
$result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);
```

with

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the connection resource/instance as the first parameter is the style of the [mysqli extension](http://docs.php.net/book.mysqli), which you should use, instead of passing the resource as the second parameter (optional) - which is how the old and now [deprecated mysql_* extension](http://docs.php.net/intro.mysql) does it. mysql_* will [be removed with the upcoming php version 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7).

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT `in`,`Name`,`Email` FROM tablename";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
if ( !$result ) {
    die('query failed: '.$mysqli->error);
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if ( !$row ) {
    echo '0 results';
}
else {
    do {
        echo "in: " . $row["in"]. " - Name: " . $row["Name"]. " - Email: " . $row["Email"]. "<br>\r\n";
    }
    while( NULL!=($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [mysqli extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "your_db";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "in: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["Name"]. " - Email: " . $row["Email"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Are mysqli extensions supported in PHP 4.4.4?  That is what is currently running on the server I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This is your confic.php file:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database_name";

$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$connection) {

    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

And make new php file and include your config file:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        ?>
            <div class="about-text">
                <?php
                    echo "In: ".$row["in"]."Name: ". $row['Name'].","."Email: ".$row['Email']."</br>";
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}else{
    echo "There is no Result!!!!";
}
mysql_close($connection);
```

i think this will help you.